# Is Bleach:Thousand-Year Blood War based on the manga?

Tags: bleach

I am on episode 4 of this series and I swear to Yamamoto-sama that I've seen this story before. Either on a manga or some movie.

Going to Hueco Mundo, rescuing Dodon-something, fighting that soldier guy, etc. I could have sworn I've seen it all before. I haven't found anything on Google, though, so I'm not actually sure.

My question ***is there*** material this series is showing that already was shown before or is this going to be another Sinbad Shazaam situation?

TLDR; is this story from some manga or OVA that I might've already seen before?